# Custom module grid container will not show

Tags: magento-1.9, php, grid, grid-layout

I know this question has been asked for so many times here on SO but nothing helped me to solve my issue.

[image]

I am trying to display a grid on my modules index page but it is not showing, I tried to `var_dump` `Mage::getModel('custombundle/bundle')->getCollection()` in a loop and it gave me output of data. Below is what I have coded so far:

**config.xml**

```
<?xml version="1.0"?>
<config>
    <modules>
        <Company_CustomBundle>
            <version>1.0.1</version>
        </Company_CustomBundle>
    </modules>
    <admin>
        <routers>
            <adminhtml>
                <args>
                    <modules>
                        <company_custombundle before="Mage_Adminhtml">Company_CustomBundle_Adminhtml</company_custombundle>
                    </modules>
                </args>
            </adminhtml>
        </routers>
    </admin>

    <global>
        <helpers>
            <custombundle>
                <class>Company_CustomBundle_Helper</class>
            </custombundle>
        </helpers>

        <!-- Blocks -->
        <blocks>
            <company_custombundle>
                <class>Company_CustomBundle_Block</class>
            </company_custombundle>
        </blocks>

        <models>
            <custombundle>
                <class>Company_CustomBundle_Model</class>
                <resourceModel>custombundle_resource</resourceModel>
            </custombundle>
            <custombundle_resource>

                <class>Company_CustomBundle_Model_Resource</class>

                <entities>
                    <basket>
                        <table>custombundle_basket</table>
                    </basket>
                    <bundle>
                        <table>custombundle_bundle</table>
                    </bundle>
                </entities>

            </custombundle_resource>
        </models>

        <resources>

            <custombundle_setup>
                <setup>
                    <module>Company_CustomBundle</module>
                    <class>Company_CustomBundle_Model_Resource_Setup</class>
                </setup>
            </custombundle_setup>

            <custombundle_write>
                <connection>
                    <use>core_write</use>
                </connection>
            </custombundle_write>

            <custombundle_read>
                <connection>
                    <use>core_read</use>
                </connection>
            </custombundle_read>

        </resources>

    </global>

    <adminhtml>

        <!-- Layouts Configuration Starts -->
        <layout>
            <updates>
                <custombundle>
                    <file>custombundle.xml</file>
                </custombundle>
            </updates>
        </layout>
        <!-- !! Layouts Configuration -->

        <menu>
            <custombundle module="custombundle">
                <title>Custom Bundle</title>
                <sort_order>100</sort_order>
                <children>
                    <index module="custombundle">
                        <title>Custom Bundle</title>
                        <sort_order>0</sort_order>
                        <action>adminhtml/custombundle/index</action>
                    </index>

                    <other module="custombundle">
                        <title>Other</title>
                        <sort_order>0</sort_order>
                        <action>adminhtml/custombundle/other</action>
                    </other>
                </children>
            </custombundle>
        </menu>
    </adminhtml>

</config>
```

**app/design/adminhtml/default/default/layout/custombundle.xml**

```
<?xml version="1.0"?>

<layout version="0.1.0">

    <adminhtml_custombundle_index> <!-- custombundle controller index action -->
        <reference name="content">
            <block type="custombundle/adminhtml_custombundle_bundle" name="list_combination" />
        </reference>
    </adminhtml_custombundle_index>
</layout>
```

**controllers/Adminhtml/CustombundleController.php**

```
public function indexAction()
{
    $this->loadLayout();
    $this->_setActiveMenu('custombundle/index');
    $this->renderLayout();
}
```

**Block/Adminhtml/Custombundle/Bundle.php**

```
class Company_CustomBundle_Block_Adminhtml_Custombundle_Bundle extends Mage_Adminhtml_Block_Widget_Grid_Container
{
    public function __construct()
    {
        $this->_controller = 'adminhtml_custombundle_bundle';
        $this->_blockGroup = 'company_custombundle';
        $this->_headerText = Mage::helper('company_custombundle')->__('Custom Bundle Category combinations');
        $this->_addButtonLabel = Mage::helper('company_custombundle')->__('Add Item');
        parent::__construct();
    }
}
```

**Block/Adminhtml/Custombundle/Bundle/Grid.php**

```
class Company_CustomBundle_Block_Adminhtml_Custombundle_Bundle_Grid extends Mage_Adminhtml_Block_Widget_Grid
{
    public function __construct()
    {
        parent::__construct();
        $this->setId('bundleGrid');
        $this->setDefaultSort('bundle_id');
        $this->setDefaultDir('DESC');
        $this->setSaveParametersInSession(true);
    }

    protected function _prepareCollection()
    {
        $collection = Mage::getModel('custombundle/bundle')->getCollection();
        $this->setCollection($collection);

        return parent::_prepareCollection();
    }

    protected function _prepareColumns()
    {
        $this->addColumn('bundle_id', array(
                'header' => 'ID',
                'align' => 'right',
                'width' => '50px',
                'index' => 'bundle_id',
        ));

        $this->addColumn('assigned_category_id', array(
              'header' => 'Assigned with',
              'align' => 'left',
              'index' => 'assigned_category_id',
        ));

        $this->addColumn('category_id', array(
              'header' => 'Category',
              'align' => 'left',
              'index' => 'category_id',
        ));

        return parent::_prepareColumns();
    }

    public function getRowUrl($row)
    {
         return $this->getUrl('*/*/edit', array('id' => $row->getId()));
    }
}
```

Comment: Can you update the question with new code? Also check for errors in log files if any.

Comment: errors anot getting generated, updated the question

Answer (score 2, accepted):

In a quick look, I think there is something wrong with the protected property value `$_controller` of your grid container. So try to use this.

```
class Company_CustomBundle_Block_Adminhtml_Custombundle_Bundle extends Mage_Adminhtml_Block_Widget_Grid_Container
{
    public function __construct()
    {
        $this->_controller = 'adminhtml_custombundle_bundle';
        $this->_blockGroup = 'company_custombundle';
        $this->_headerText = Mage::helper('company_custombundle')->__('Custom Bundle Category combinations');
        $this->_addButtonLabel = Mage::helper('company_custombundle')->__('Add Item');
        parent::__construct();
    }
}
```

The only change here is,  `adminhtml_custombundle` is changed to `adminhtml_custombundle_bundle`. This value is used to effectively identify grid class. As per definition of your classes, that tail part (ie `_bundle`) is also essential to correctly point towards your grid class. (ie `Company_CustomBundle_Block_Adminhtml_Custombundle_Bundle_Grid`)

### EDIT - 1

I think your router definition is also wrong . you need to correct that in your `config.xml` file like this

```
<admin>
    <routers>
        <adminhtml>
            <args>
                <modules>
                    <company_custombundle before="Mage_Adminhtml">Company_CustomBundle_Adminhtml</company_custombundle>
                </modules>
            </args>
        </adminhtml>
    </routers>
</admin>
```

The definition that you are using is deprecated from Magento 1.9 version. It is also not recommended to use.

There is also changes needed in the menu definition section as per above router change.

Try to use this:

```
<menu>
    <custombundle module="custombundle">
        <title>Custom Bundle</title>
        <sort_order>100</sort_order>
        <children>
            <index module="custombundle">
                <title>Custom Bundle</title>
                <sort_order>0</sort_order>
                <action>adminhtml/custombundle/index</action>
            </index>

            <other module="custombundle">
                <title>Other</title>
                <sort_order>0</sort_order>
                <action>adminhtml/custombundle/other</action>
            </other>
        </children>
    </custombundle>
</menu>
```

Changes here are inside `action` node.

### Edit - 2

Please keep the grid container change also in your code. It is essential. If it is not working, then try to simplify your `indexAction()` method in your controller like this.

```
public function indexAction()
{
    $this->loadLayout();
    $this->_setActiveMenu('custombundle/index');
    $this->renderLayout();
}
```

After this changes are made, do not forget to clear your cache before test it.

Comment: Hi @rajeev-k-tomy I was expecting your answer :D , sorry but this didn't work for me...

Comment: can you see anything while you click on your custom menu ?

Comment: I am taken to the controllers action view but the block is not getting rendered there... let me update question with screenshot..

Comment: please see my edit. there are some more mistakes I can see now. Keep first change too.

Comment: @SagarGuhe, update `menu` tag as per suggestion, it should work.

Comment: @rajeev-k-tomy now page not found error is coming url is like this now `...index.php/admin/custombundle_index/index/key/92604aa723b0661869224965313815ae/`

Comment: Okay. can you change `action` value to `adminhtml/custombundle` and try again. If that is not working, please try `adminhtml/custombundle/index` too. Let me know whether that works for you.

Comment: @SagarGuhe please see the menu section in answer if my comment is not clear for you.

Comment: yes the menu is working now but the problem is still same with better routing..

Comment: are you sure my first change (change on grid container) is still there ?

Comment: yes it is still there

Comment: @SagarGuhe Please see my edit. Can you try that.

Comment: i cannot see that change in your edited code. so make sure that is there.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/52931/discussion-between-sagar-guhe-and-rajeev-k-tomy).

Answer (score 3):

Try below updates, First, using `<use>admin</admin>` is not a good approach anymore. You need to use it as below,
Replace in your **config.xml**

```
<admin>
    <routers>
        <custombundle>
            <use>admin</use>
            <args>
                <module>Company_CustomBundle</module>
                <frontName>admin_custombundle</frontName>
            </args>
        </custombundle>
    </routers>
</admin>
```

With

```
<admin> 
    <routers>
         <adminhtml> 
             <args> 
                <modules> 
                    <Company_CustomBundle after="Mage_Adminhtml">Company_CustomBundle_Adminhtml</Company_CustomBundle> 
                </modules> 
            </args>
       </adminhtml>
   </routers> 
</admin>
```

Now update your **app/design/adminhtml/default/default/layout/custombundle.xml**
with below code.

```
<?xml version="1.0"?>
<layout version="0.1.0">
    <adminhtml_custombundle_index>
        <reference name="content">
            <block type="custombundle/adminhtml_custombundle_bundle" name="list_combination" />
        </reference>
    </adminhtml_custombundle_index>
</layout>
```

Comment: Now page not found error is coming..

Comment: I have updated the question with suggested improvments